# File upload form in HTML site with saving on Google drive or Dropbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, contact-form

I have built a contact form (using [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) to save results in Google Sheets) for my company website. But I also need to add a file upload function to this form. Google Forms only allows image attachments. I need images, pdf, rar, etc.

I have found a [JS script](https://script.google.com/d/1x3p9ZAv-SafEK06r_Vr7fVuUNtEfBg1SGhmSYWjQ0kuPTk-y55a7Nink/edit?usp=sharing) for file upload, but the form works only directly on the link, and I can't use this form on my site. Also, creating many folders doesn't work entirely, but seems to depend on the inserted name.

How can I build some form to allow uploading files for anyone on my cloud account and integrate it in the contact form on Company site?

P.S. I can't use `PHP` scripts on Company site, only raw HTML files.

Comment: Does your company has a Google for Work account? if so, you can deploy the script and make it only accessible for the people in the company domain

Comment: I need that form for clients, so anyone can upload files, because it is a contact form.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use Jotform and use the Dropbox or Google Drive plugin in Jotform.
With that you don't have to worry about securing your form and checking the integrity of the uploaded files.
Also: Jotform has no php.

Here is the link: [Jotform Dropbox plugin](http://apps.jotform.com/category/file_sharing_and_storage)